# What is Frege equivalent to Haskell's Fractional?

Tags: haskell, frege

This definition is valid in `ghci`:

```
recip :: Fractional a ⇒ a → a
recip n = 1 / n
```

Trying it in `frege-repl` I got:

```
E <console>.fr:6: can't resolve `Fractional`, did you mean `Exceptional`
    perhaps?
```

["Hoogling"](http://hoogle.haskell.org:8081/?hoogle=Fractional) `Fractional` gives me nothing.

Comment: Try hoogling `(/)` instead.

Comment: @DanielWagner Should this be called "Froogling" instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Frege analog of `Fractional` appears to be [`Real`](http://www.frege-lang.org/doc/frege/prelude/PreludeBase#Real), which offers two operations:

```
(/) ∷ Real r ⇒ r → r → r
fromDouble ∷ Real r ⇒ Double → r
```